# Returning a struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, return

I am writing a program to define a struct and then write a function that will create and return a struct that was previously defined. My struct is as follows:

```
 struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_NAMES];//Symbolic constant with max set to 200
    int birthYear;
    int startYear;
    };
```

And my function[s] is[are]:

```
struct Employee* makeEmployee(char* nameOf, int birthYearOf, int startYearOf)
{
      struct Employee *e;
      e = (struct Employee *) malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));

      (*e).name = mystrcpy((*e).name, *nameOf);
      (*e).birthYear = birthYearOf;
      (*e).startYear = startYearOf;

      return e;
}
//edited in from comments below OP:
char* mystrcpy(char dest, const char src)
{ 
    while((*dest++ = *src++) != '\0')
    { 
        ; 
    } 
    return dest; 
}
```

My error that I get is: mystring.c: In function 'makeEmployee':
mystring.c:147: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
mystring.c:147: error: incompatible types in assignment

enter code here

Comment: You need to show the lines that are actually generating the errors, or no one will be able to see what is going on there. I don't see a "strcpy" anywhere, is `mystrcpy` a macro? If so you need to show it.

Comment: Write `e->name`, not `(*e).name`. The error is (probably) the second argument of `mystrcpy()`, which should presumably be a `char` pointer (`nameOf`) and not a `char` (`*nameOf`).

Comment: What does `mystrcpy` look like?

Comment: Sorry I should have put that there. mystrcpy is char* mystrcpy(char *dest, const char* src){
  while((*dest++ = *src++) != '\0'){
    ;
  }
  return dest;
}

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this website and the code did not format

Comment: prototype of mystrcpy (if you want it to copy strings) should include argument for strings: `char* mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`

Comment: Please include the definition of `mystrcpy` in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

***Several things***:
prototype of mystrcpy needs to use arguments for strings, not a value for char:
***Change:***

```
char* mystrcpy(char dest, const char src){...}
```

***To:***

```
char* mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src){...}
```

In C, casting the return of malloc is not correct (it is in C++, Not C).
***Change:***

```
  e = (struct Employee *) malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

***To:***

```
  e = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

In this segment, you are attempting to assign a value to a string using the `=` operator:

```
(*e).name = mystrcpy((*e).name, *nameOf); 
          ^//not correct
```

Use string functions for string assignments.  For example:

```
strcpy((*e).name,  mystrcpy((*e).name, nameOf)); (or your custom version, mystrcpy once it works)
//(although this is redundant)
mystrcpy((*e).name,  mystrcpy((*e).name, nameOf));
```

Your custom `mystrcpy()` needs to insure it returns a null terminated string.  This version is modified to use the `[]` operator and an explicit index (i) for readability of illustration:

```
char* mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{ 
    int i=0;
    while((src[i]) != '\0')
    { 
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    } 
    dest[i] = 0;//null terminate copied string
    return dest; 
}
```

Below is a compilable version of your code, including modifications mentioned above:

```
#define MAX_NAMES 80
struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_NAMES];//Symbolic constant with max set to 200
    int birthYear;
    int startYear;
};
//Prototypes:
struct Employee* makeEmployee(char* nameOf, int birthYearOf, int startYearOf);
char* mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

int main(void)
{
    struct Employee Emp, *pEmp; //create and initialize an instance and pointer to struct
    pEmp = &Emp;//note, there is nothing to malloc when initializing this way.

    pEmp = makeEmployee("somename", 2007, 2015);
    //do something with pEmp here
    free(pEmp);//memory allocated in makeEmployee must be freed  
               //by the way, if you prototyped your function
               //to include the pointer to struct as an argument
               //it can be malloc'd and free'd in the same function
    return 0;
}

struct Employee* makeEmployee(char* nameOf, int birthYearOf, int startYearOf)
{
    struct Employee *e;

    e = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    strcpy((*e).name,  mystrcpy((*e).name, nameOf));        
    // or use mystrcpy((*e).name,  mystrcpy((*e).name, nameOf));
    (*e).birthYear = birthYearOf;
    (*e).startYear = startYearOf;

    return e;  
  }

char* mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{ 
    int i=0;
    while((src[i]) != '\0')
    { 
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    } 
    dest[i] = 0;
    return dest; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a struct, simply return by pointer (address copy). So you'd write:

```
void creat(struct employee *emp, char *name, int birthYear, int startYear)
{
    strcpy(emp->name, name);
    emp->birthYear = birthYear;
    emp->startYear = startYear;
}
```

In caller:

```
struct employee bob;

creat(&bob, "Bob", 1985, 2000);
```

Now, you can use `bob` like a normal employee.

Comment: It's also possible to return a struct by value.